# Kubernetes Angular deployed in Nginx to access endpoint of app running in same container using ClusterIP service

Tags: angular, kubernetes, nginx

I have simple Spring Boot web-app that is deployed in Kubernetes cluster, which is exposed as `ClusterIP`. I am able to access the endpoint using the service using `tmp nginx pod`, by curl command.

```bash
curl -i http://service-name:port/api/end-point
```

The Angular app deployed in NGINX, base URL is configured to use `service-name:port/api/`. There is no `LoadBalancer` or Ingress configured in the cluster, so I port forward the Angular app service and then I am able to access the Angular web-app but it is not loading the data.

The Angular web-app, should hit the backend service and fetch the data. By `kubect exec` to the NGINX Angular web-app, issuing `curl http://service-name:port/api/endpoint` produces results with HTTP code 200 OK.

```json
server {
  listen 80;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  gzip on;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    autoindex on;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
  
 error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
 location = /50x.html {
     root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
 }
}
```

The Angluar app uses `HttpClient` to hit the endpoint and based on the rendered data the App displays the data. What is notice from browser developer tools, is no data found.

Comment: do you have any logs? I mean run `kubectl logs -f ANGULAR_POD_NAME` to see is there any error logs?

Comment: As suggested by @mahdi check the logs and also if possible provide the steps or give your network configurations. So that we can further debug this problem

Comment: The Angular application is presumably running in your local browser, not a Kubernetes Pod, so it can't use a ClusterIP Service to call the backend.  Look into setting up an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) to make the front-end code and back-end interface accessible from outside the cluster.

Comment: There was no logs other than only request from the browser in the Nginx access.log. As @DavidMaze mentioned probably the Angular app is running from the browser, and the httpclient is requesting from the browser. Probably I think adding the following configuration  ` location /api/endpoint { proxy_pass http://my-service:8080 }` in the nginx config might address.

Answer (score 0):

In local, below is what I did

Step 1:
Port forwarded the service-name (service), so I am able to access the backend `http:\\localhost:port.`

Step 2:
Update the `C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts` to include

```
127.0.0.1  service-name.<namespace>
```

The Angular app service was already accessible via `http://localhost:80`.

With the above setup able to access the changes.

For production like environment, use of below option might be considered

- Ingress controller to route traffic exposing a NodePort.
- To update Nginx configuration with proxy_path directive, still the backend endpoint should be discoverable externally.